# The call between InitializeComponent(); is ambiguous?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

My error is:

> Error 4   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Grub2._0.Time.InitializeComponent()' and
>   'Grub2._0.Time.InitializeComponent()'

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

namespace Grub2._0
{
    public partial class Time2 : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public void Time2.()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (AMRadioButton.IsChecked == true)
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PolicemanFood.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            else if (PMRadioButton.IsChecked == false)
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Weed.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            else
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/BurgerKing.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: InitializeComponent(); is.  Visual Studio recommended that I write an InitializeComponent() method that handled an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I met this proplem when I put 2 wpf projects in one solution which shares some libs, and then open the 2 at the same time. Seems the 2 visual studio instance want generate code for the 2 exe at the same time, which causes conflicts.

Closing one of them solves the problem.

Comment: Just encountered the same warning in Rider. Appears after checkout'ing another commit. Simple restart of IDE fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

namespace Grub2._0
{
    public partial class Time2 : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public Time2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (AMRadioButton.IsChecked == true)
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PolicemanFood.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            else if (PMRadioButton.IsChecked == false)
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Weed.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            else
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/BurgerKing.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
}
```

Removed the *void* keyword and period after Time2 on the constructor.

Comment: Haha classic, thank you.  Well I removed them in my mind.  Edited the answer.

Comment: Still had the issue. I have a Time.xaml.cs as well as a Time2.xaml.cs (for different .xaml files).  I ended up deleting all of Time2 since there wasn't much to it and am going to try again.

Comment: Make sure the namespace is the same as well... I see it has that period in there.  You'll have to rename them all both in your code files and in the project properties.